# Why would Html.AgilityPack miss some image tags?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am using the html agility pack and did something like this

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://test.com");

int count = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img").Count();
```

I get `38` back.

When I go to that page and do `$('img').size();` I get `43` back. Why is there a difference? Is `"//img"` just looking for root ones?

Is that why I might be missing some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is "//img" just looking for
>   root ones?

No it looking for descendant nodes (children, grandchildren, etc. of the current node). Your xpath expression selects all the images from the document.

> When I go to that page and do $('img').size(); I get 43 back.

My assumption - some of the images are created dynamically via javascript. HtmlAgilityPack cannot handle this.

By the way, for the `http://test.com` I got 87 image nodes with AgilityPack (`doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img").Count()`), and 87 image nodes from the Chome console (`$('img').size()`).

**EDIT**: `HtmlWeb.Load()` method internally uses [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class to get data. The role of AgilityPack is *to parse the data correctly*. It's completely possible that some web resources return different content for the same URI depending on some of request headers like `User-Agent` and others. E.g. `User-Agent` header could be set via `HtmlWeb.UserAgent` property.

Comment: ya test.come is not the page I am using(just something to fill in). Hmm not sure to do if that is the case they are doing it dynamically.

Comment: Actually looking in the source code through Google chrome I get 48 images but it seems like at least 10 are commented out. So maybe they get ignored by htmlAgilityPack(what would give me a count of 38). Still not sure why there is a difference between jquery as it finds 43 so what is it ignoring some commented out ones and not others?

Comment: @chobo2, try to turn off javascript. I think the number of images should be the same. Also edited my answer with one more possible explanation of this.