# Need Help in Understanding a confusion while making Web Crawlers to get total Links Count

Tags: c#, regex, web-crawler, webrequest

I have tried to get a starting to making a web crawler. Was progressing well till I got this confusion that I can't understand. I have written the following code:

I am passing `http://www.google.com` as the string `URL`

```
public void crawlURL(string URL, string depth)
{
    if (!checkPageHasBeenCrawled(URL))
    {
        PageContent = getURLContent(URL);
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(PageContent, "href=\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        int count = matches.Count;
    }
} 

private string getURLContent(string URL)
{
    string content;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.UserAgent = "Fetching contents Data";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    stream.Close();
    return content;
}
```

Problem:
I am trying to get all the Links of the page(http://www.google.com or any other website) but I see less count of the links from the Regex matches. It gives me links count to be 19 while when i checked the source code manually for the word "href=" it gave me 41 occurances. I can't understand why it is giving me less count of the word from the code.

Comment: "Checked the source code manually". You mean the content of `PageContent`, or when you open the link in a browser? Because in the latter case you might get a different page due to personalization.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't parse javascript, so any links which are added via scripting won't show up.

Comment: avoid using regex...use a parser

Comment: See a similar question: [Why would Html.AgilityPack miss some image tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729171/102112)

Comment: also, you are searching for `href="`, but on google you find a lot of javascript with `a.href=document...` which wont be matched by our regex. (it also will ignore `href='` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed and tested your regex pattern.  The following should work more efficiently. It gets 11 matches from google.ca

```
public void crawlURL(string URL)
        {

            PageContent = getURLContent(URL);
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(PageContent, "(href=\"https?://[a-z0-9-._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+(?=\"|$))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

            int count = matches.Count;

        }

        private string getURLContent(string URL)
        {
            string content;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.UserAgent = "Fetching contents Data";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            return content;
        }
```